# How can stop a mule project in Mule standalone(server)?

Tags: project, mule

I am a beginner in Mule
How can stop a Mule project in Mule standalone(server)?

Answer (score 1):

You can undeploy any application by removing the [anchor file](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Application+Deployment)

Answer (score 1):

You either delete the anchor file or click on undeploying application

Answer (score 1):

Remove the anchor.txt file, it will undeploy the application

Answer (score 1):

Please delete the anchor.txt file, it will stop the application

Answer (score 0):

you could also press ctrl+c in the command window where your mule is running, then press Y and hit enter when prompted - this will cause shutdown. removing anchor will work too

Comment: The ctrl+c command will stop the server not only a mule application. The wright answer is removing the anchor file.

Answer (score -1):

Kill the process from task manager

Answer (score -1):

If you are using STandalone deployment , Make sure you should remove the -Anchor.txt file from the apps folder and rerun the mule.bat file to restart the server. It will automatically undeploy the application from server.

Please go through my video on this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngf_IVXSTAc

Comment: Removing the anchor file will un-deploy the application. There is no need to restart the server.

Answer (score -1):

Please do either of the following:
delete anchor.txt file or
undeploy the appliction or
kill the process in task mamnager

Comment: Kill the process will shutdown the mule server.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using tomcat as your standalone server

> C:>tomcat6 /ss/tomcat6

where 
/SS/ - Stop Service. Stops the Tomcat Windows Service, if running.
tomcat6 is service name, you can use your custom service name